# Get bash where bash script executed from

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to be able to execute a bash script located in my home directory with the command `~/script_name.sh` from any directory and then in the script, get the directory that it was ran from.

eg. I'm in the directory `/foo/bar/baz`, and execute `/foo/script.sh`, and it prints out `/foo/bar/baz`

`pwd` and `$0`/`$BASH_SOURCE` give me the directory my shell starts in and the path to the script in my home directory respectively.

Comment: `pwd` is the right answer. If you believe seeing something else, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @thatotherguy Is right. Here is a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/1482133/4175515

Comment: If you add a [mre] letting someone else reproduce the problem, let me know. That said -- `pwd` or, better, `$PWD` is genuinely the right answer here. (BTW -- in the future, tag for bash *or* sh, but not both at once; bash is mostly a superset of the POSIX sh specification, but sometimes they diverge).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking the **external** command `pwd`, consider using `$PWD` instead. If you want to protect against some rogue code having explicitly changed `PWD`, do a `cd .` (which is an **internal** command) first, which restores `PWD` to the correct value.